# Is this edit rejection right?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416875/formating-json-to-table-on-zapier-code) where I thought there was unnecessary noise in that question and edited it. But OP rejected the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10026799) with an irrelevant reject reason.

Should I re-edit the question again? (OP may reject it again!) or Should I just add a comment and leave it as it is?

What will be the appropriate thing I can do in this case?

Comment: Thats the default edit reject reason afaik.

Comment: I have made that edit - it was perfectly reasonable, the OP shoudn't have rejected it. I suspect it would have been approved through the normal *"jury of your peers"* method.

Comment: Looks like the kind of OP who would rollback if someone with full editing privileges did that to their question.

Comment: @BoltClock start the (bolt) clock!

Comment: Some newer users don't like having their questions edited, and if given the chance, will reject any that is suggested. Hopefully this user can be informed about how editing works here and will change that mindset.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Thanks for the edit and the comment.

Comment: @Kendra - Yeah, that would be right the right thing to do.

Comment: Who had money on *"will say sorry?"* - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416875/formating-json-to-table-on-zapier-code?noredirect=1#comment54625022_33416875

Comment: Personally, when I see an edit on a question, I check the editor's profile to see if this is a topic they know about and maybe I'm just phrasing my question wrong.  If they have some solid answers on the topic I'll likely just let it go, otherwise if they have a ton of edits / revisions (especially across areas) and hardly any answers, I will typically go back and compare what I have to what they have and do a manual revision of my own or reject it altogether.  I don't want someone who doesn't know the technology better than I do trying to translate my question to others.  Risk vs reward...

Comment: @Magisch: There isn't any *default* reason; you have to select one each time.

Comment: @Nick you should accept/reject edits based on their content not the profile/history of the editor...

Comment: @andy I'm not of the vote to accept someone else's suggestions if they haven't demonstrated knowledge of the area.  Being a programming site, there are a multitude of languages that all have different syntaxes, and I don't see where a person's personal pet peeve of a comma location for instance outweighs the initial question as it could introduce bugs into the question that weren't there previously.  By the same token, people shouldn't be making edits unless it makes the question easier to understand.  I have seen plenty of trivial edits that made no impact on the question, ergo no real value.

Comment: "I'm not of the vote to accept someone else's suggestions if they haven't demonstrated knowledge of the area" I completely disagree with you there... Also, if they have a high reputation it's never going to be a suggestion anyway but a direct edit. (Changing *code* is very different story to english/phrasing, edits should very very rarely be to code.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While the suggestion *was* good, in the end, the OP has the right to approve or rejects edits as he / she sees fit. (Within reason, of course)

You could comment on the post, explaining that noise such as the smileys and "thanks" don't belong on SO, asking the OP to remove those. Other than that, there's not much you can do.
Suggesting the edit again could result in the OP simply declining the suggestion again. That'd be a waste of everyone's time.

A 2k user can *(and [did](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33416875/2))* directly apply the edit, and hope for the best.

So, to answer your question:
No, the rejection wasn't *right*, even though the OP has the right to do so.

Comment: Tbh for cases like this a new user shouldn't be able to roll back a peer reviewed edit or edit by a 2k+ user

Comment: @Magisch: That'd be impossible to implement fairly. Edit reviews are _broken_ due to robo-reviewers.